No puedo limprimir una matrix en Java, no entiendo el mensaje de error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
El programa me compila pero al ejecutarlo en la terminal me da el siguiente mensaje de error el cual no entiendo, no se que hice mal:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
at DynamicMatrix.main(DynamicMatrix.java:24)
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DynamicMatrix{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int my_columns = 0,
                my_count = 0,
                my_rows = 0;
                    
        Scanner enter_value = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("How many rows do you want?: ");
        my_rows = enter_value.nextInt();

        System.out.print("How many columns do you want?: ");
        my_columns = enter_value.nextInt();
        
        int my_matrix[][] = new int[my_rows][my_columns];
        
        for(int j = 0; j < my_rows; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < my_columns; i++){
                my_matrix[j][i] = my_count;
                my_count++;
                System.out.print("[" + my_matrix[my_rows][my_columns] + "] ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
    }
}


La cosa esta en que estas haciendo un bucle y las variables mycoumns y myrows esta saliendose de la longitud de la matriz, prueba a restarle -1, te quedaria algo asi
System.out.print("[" + my_matrix[my_rows-1][my_columns-1] + "] "); o tambien y lo recomendado seria imprimir la posicion que te dan los indices que es para lo que has hecho el bucleSystem.out.print("[" + my_matrix[i][j] + "] ");

El error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3 indica que estás intentando acceder a una posición en la matriz que está fuera de los límites definidos.
El problema está en la línea donde intentas imprimir los elementos de la matriz:
System.out.print("[" + my_matrix[my_rows][my_columns] + "] ");

Aquí my_rows y my_columns son los valores totales de filas y columnas que ingresaste, no los índices actuales del bucle. En lugar de usar my_rows y my_columns para acceder a los elementos de la matriz, deberías usar j e i, que son los índices actuales de las filas y columnas que has definido en el bucle
El codigo completo te quedaria asi:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DynamicMatrix{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int my_columns = 0,
                my_count = 0,
                my_rows = 0;
                    
        Scanner enter_value = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("How many rows do you want?: ");
        my_rows = enter_value.nextInt();

        System.out.print("How many columns do you want?: ");
        my_columns = enter_value.nextInt();
        
        int my_matrix[][] = new int[my_rows][my_columns];
        
        for(int j = 0; j < my_rows; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < my_columns; i++){
                my_matrix[j][i] = my_count;
                my_count++;
                System.out.print("[" + my_matrix[j][i] + "] ");  // Corregido aquí
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
    }
}

PD: no se si estabas imprimiendo la posicion de my_rows y my_columns en ese caso supongo que quieres imprimir la ultima posicion de la matriz cada vuelta que da el bucle, en ese caso comentamelo y te ayudo a hacerlo
